# How can I completely remove all files from the device

Tags: rom-flashing

I recently installed a custom rom over my Android after flashing, removing all user data and wiping dalvik cahe etc.

But after installing it I ind out that the old files are still there such whatsapp folders and other apps also.

Why is that ? how can I completely remove  everything from my device and reinstall and fresh rom.

Comment: Did you wipe `/data/media` or did `fastboot -w`?

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: You can wipe Media from Custom Recovery, or issue fastboot command from PC when the device is booted into bootloader mode and connected to PC via USB cable. Try the first one since it's easy.

Comment: Since wiping /data/media will wipe your "internal SD card", backup your personal files if you've stored them there.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to that, go to Settings > Storage  and touch  Erase xxx Storage for all the types of storage. That should wipe all your stored files.